# Input in terms of variables

Tags: python, variables, input, plot

I am making a simple function plotter in python using pygame. I want the user to be able to enter the function in terms of `x` and `y` through the console. For example:
`math.sin(x) + math.sin(y)` should be a valid input.
How do I accomplish that?
*Note:*`x` *and* `y` *haven't been assigned any value as the value would replace the variable in the input.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `exec` statement with a def statement you can create a function from a string arg given by the user.

```
>>> arg = raw_input() 
>>> arg
'math.sin(x) + math.cos(y)'
>>> exec 'def f(x,y): return ' + arg
>>> f
<function f at 0x000000000021F9E48>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without using eval for each point? It eats a lot of computing power...

Comment: As far as I know eval function and exec statement are the only way to transform a string to code. In the case where you want a def statement you must use exec.

Answer (score 0):

But you aren't "using eval for each point". Once `exec` compiles the code `f()` behaves just like a normal function. Do some timings with this code to see for yourself

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

'''
exec speed test
'''

import sys, math
from random import seed, random

def main():
    m = len(sys.argv) > 1 and int(sys.argv[1]) or 250000

    def f(x, y):
        return math.sin(x) + math.cos(y)

    funcstr = 'math.sin(x) + math.cos(y)'
    exec 'def g(x,y): return ' + funcstr in globals(), locals()

    #print f, g

    seed(42)

    z = 0.0
    for i in xrange(m):
        z += f(random(), random())
        #z += g(random(), random())

    print z


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On *nix you can do `time python progname.py`; sorry, I don't know the Windows equivalent.